# How to set minimum width on a LinearLayout element when using weightSum and layout_weight

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I set the width of my LinearLayout's childs as percentages of the layout.

It displays fine on 7 and 10 inches screens, but on 5 inches, the given percentage yields a width too small for the text.

The child's minWidth attribute is ignored.

How can I set a minimum width on a child ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_file_seek_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_file_playing_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar_source_file"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="92"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Should Work

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_file_seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_file_playing_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar_source_file"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="92"
        android:indeterminate="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Poor answer, try using some words to explain what you changed and why...

Answer (score 0):

`android:minWidth` is ignored cause `android:layout_width="0dp"`. You can put separate layout into `layout-normal` directory without `android:layout_weight` parameters:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_file_seek_bar"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_file_playing_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
/>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar_source_file"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
/>
```

Comment: I do want the child to be a percentage of the layout on 7 and 10 inches screens, hence the android:layout_width="0dp". I don't have a layout-normal directory. What is it used for ?

Comment: @matdev You can define different layouts for different screen sizes. More info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thanks for pointing me in that direction @birdy. However, I'd like to keep setting the default width as a percentage. Having the minWidth attribute working along with layout_weight would avoid having to create layouts for different screen sizes